# What is the best way to declare an attribute that contains a certain amount of data?

Tags: python, oop, class-attributes

I'm kind of new to **OOP** and I'd like to know what is the best way to declare an attribute that contains a certain amount of data in it ?

I do really hesitate between using a `dict` or an other `class` to do it.

So here what I'm basically trying to do :

```py
class Character:
   def __init__(self):
      self.health = {
         "maximum" : 100,
         "current" : 100
      }
```

To access the current health value I'll need to do :

```py
current_health = character.health["current"]
```

But I've also discorvered that I could do this :

```py
class Character:
   def __init__(self):
      self.health = Health()
      self.health.maximum = 100
      self.health.current = 100

class Health:
   def __init__(self):
      self.maximum = 0
      self.current = 0
```

So to access the current health value :

```py
current_health = character.health.current
```

I'd like to know what is the best solution ?

As I plan to make my **repository** public, I want it do be as comfy as possible and as less disturbing as possible.

Thank you in advance for your answer !

Comment: this is sort of an opinion based question, because there are other ways to achieve this, for instance using a `namedtuple` as the attribute

Comment: It totally depends on what you need `health` to be.

Comment: Another way, if you only have these two attributes is to simply do `self.health_max` and `self.health_current`. However, f you have other health attributes, or possibly methods that you may want to call for health, then the health class will likely be your best approach.

Comment: Definitely opinion-based; opting to close, though it's a natural question to ask, just not a good Q for SO. At the end of the day, the differences in accessing are pretty minimal; `character.health.max` vs `character.health['max']` vs `character.max_health` are all fine. In my opinion, your health is not a key value store, and doesn't need a namespace, so I would just opt for separate attributes. It's easy to use and understand and adding the extra code doesn't *do* anything for you.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers !